# toString method not printing

Tags: java

When I call toString(), it's calling the built-in toString() and not my custom version.

Here is my code (with unnecessary code removed to make this more of a minimal, complete, verifiable question:

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<Item extends Comparable> {

    private class Node{
      private Item item;
      private Node next;
      private Node prev;
      //methods to get/set next, prev, item
    }

    private Node head;
    private int numberOfEelements;

    //methods to add/remove items (sorted)

    public String toString(){
      Node current = head;
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      while(current != null){
        sb.append(current).append("Item: " + " ");
        current = current.getNext();
      }
      return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       DoublyLinkedList<Integer> list = new DoublyLinkedList<Integer>();
        list.sortedAdd(1);
        list.sortedAdd(5);
        list.sortedAdd(7);
        list.sortedAdd(9);
        list.sortedAdd(3);
        list.sortedAdd(2);
        list.sortedRemove(3);
        System.out.println(list.toString());

    }
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `toString` returns a String but you don't do anything with it

Comment: but i tried, system.out.println(list.tostring) still not working. what should i do with it than?

Comment: You need to create a `toString()` method override for **all** pertinent involved classes including `Node` **and** `DoublyLinkedList`.

Comment: Another problem is that you really never set next for `head`.

Comment: @glw where do you mean?

Comment: well i added the @Override, but that didnt help anything.

Comment: @Toni debug method `sortedAdd` in second use (`list.sortedAdd(5);`) you will find it. You miss refference to `head` and you are setting next/prev to new object.

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
list.toString();
```

with

```
System.out.println(list.toString());
```

Explanation: The `toString` method generates a String representation of an object, but it does not generate any output. So you have to send the result to e.g. `System.out`.

Comment: i tried this bro, it prints something like this DoublyLinkedList$Node@3cd1a2f1Item:

Comment: Yes, because that is the default String representation of any object: The name of the class and the address in memory. There are many ways to create a more meaningful output. For example you can overwrite `toString` in your `DoublyLinkedList` to iterate over the entries and create a more meaningful output by some kind of concatenation.

Comment: @Toni: That's because you're using [`Object.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) of your `Node`s. (You did not override `toString` for `Node`). Add the **content** of the nodes to the `String`, not the `Node`s.

Comment: but how should i iterate over the list. i never used iterators? :p